# How to store loads of MQTT message into MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a problem with my application that store MQTT messages into MongoDB.
I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and it opens a lot of connections to MongoDB, it throws an Exception to tell me I exceeded the 500 connections limit. And the CPU usage is constantly over 95%.

Here is the method which stores into MongoDB :

```
@Async
public void insertIntoDb(String topic, String vhost, MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
    try {
        String[] split = topic.split("/", 2);
        String deviceName = split[0];
        String topicName = (split.length > 1) ? split[1] : split[0];
        Date now = new Date();
        Object value = getValue(mqttMessage);
        String upsertId = topicRepository.upsertTopic(new Topic(topicName, deviceName, vhost, now.getTime(), value));
        boolean updateLastActivity = (topicName.equals("STS") || topicName.equals("LASTACTIVITY")) ? false : true;
        deviceRepository.upsertDevice(new Device(deviceName, vhost, now.getTime()), upsertId, updateLastActivity);
        if (typeDetectionService.isOctetStream(mqttMessage.getPayload())) {
            dataRepository.save(new Data(deviceName, topicName, vhost, new Date(), mqttMessage.getPayload()));
        } else {
            dataRepository.save(new Data(deviceName, topicName, vhost, new Date(), value));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
}
```

It uses the `insert` method from the `MongoRepository` interface, I know it's not the best way to insert massive amount of data in MongoDB and that I have to use the Bulk insert.

The problem I have is that I need to insert the data as quickly as possible in the database because it must be close to real time (I'm working with IOT Device). I thought about a List that will be filled and when it reach 1000 data (the limit to the bulk if I read correctly...) it will bulk insert in the database. Or if the list doesn't fill up quickly enough, a timeout will tell when to write all the datas.

I thought about Spring integration, but I don't know if there is a `MessageChannel` that suits my need.

If you have any suggestions, I'm open to hear it :)

Comment: You want to be close to real time while using a (mongo) dB storage. Do see now where the Problem is?

Comment: No I don't, please enlighten me